# How to set SkinID programmatically with the control?

Tags: asp.net, controls, themes

<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/YourGuruMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="AnswerQuestion.aspx.cs" Inherits="AnswerQuestion" StylesheetTheme="AnswerDesign"%>

My skin file:

My code behind:

```
 Label title;
void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    title = new Label();
    title.SkinID = "Blue";
}

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  title.Text = QuestionRequest;
        PlaceHolder2.Controls.Add(title);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the page's Theme property to the "AnswerDesign" instead of StyleSheetTheme to resolve the problem.  Also, make certain that this theme contains the Blue skin.

**UPDATE**
Change the code as follows:

// OLD CODE

```
... StylesheetTheme="AnswerDesign"%
```

// NEW CODE

```
... Theme="AnswerDesign"%
```

Comment: Theme contains Label skin..and inside it there is a label with SkinID=Blue

Comment: @WithFlyingColors, I've updated my answer.  Try changing the code this way.  It works fine here :)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you have add skin file named Blue. This is not the SkinID. Actually this file can have any name bu you must set SkinID property value in each control skin definition if you don't want to use the default. Did you read autogenerated comment at the top of skin file?